# What technology to use from web based peer-to-peer client

Tags: java, android, web, webclient, p2p

I want to create a peer-to-peer connection between android and web client. I am still looking for a technology which will enable p2p connection. Can somebody comment on those. Currently I am considering the following:

- WebRTC
- WebSockets

I want to avoid Flash, Java Applets and other plugin-based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Peer to peer term can be very misleading. If by Peer to Peer you mean a connection inside a p2p formed network, you should consider implementing protocols like JXTA.

If you mean just a connection between a web browser and Android system. You can implement it using Java Script AJAX (for UI update and Data Transfer) and A small server on android app.

You should also consider your connectivity scope. Do you want it to be available in whole internet or just local network. In former case you need a centralized server with a Valid IP or using more sophisticated Peer to Peer protocols.